# circuit breaker annotation with Spring mvc(NOT Spring-boot)

Tags: resilience4j

I am trying to use @CircuitBreaker annotation in spring-mvc project but it does not seem to work.
Does resilience4j-annotations work on a traditional non spring-boot setup?

```
@Bean
public CircuitBreaker edocCircuitBreaker() {
    LOGGER.info("Creating Circuit");
    CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
            .slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .minimumNumberOfCalls(2)
            .slidingWindowSize(2)
            .failureRateThreshold(100)
            .build();
    CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(circuitBreakerConfig);
    CircuitBreaker serviceClientCircuitBreaker =  circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("ClientCircuitBreaker");
    serviceClientCircuitBreaker.getEventPublisher().onStateTransition(this::serviceCircuitOpenHanlder);
    return serviceClientCircuitBreaker;
}



@CircuitBreaker(name="ClientCircuitBreaker")
public String sendAndReceive(String request, RequestParameters parameters) throws RuntimeException {

    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(request));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    
    
    .....
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `resilience4j-spring`. It provides a lot of `@Configuration` classes for you.

You need to import the Configuration classes:

```
@Import({ CircuitBreakerConfiguration.class, RetryConfiguration.class, TimeLimiterConfiguration.class, BulkheadConfiguration.class }
```

The `CircuitBreakerConfiguration` is important, because it configures the `CircuitBreakerAspect` bean which is needed so that annotations are working.

You have to create a `@Bean` which uses your external configuration properties file and fills and returns `CircuitBreakerConfigurationProperties`.

In resilience4j-spring-boot2 we configure it automatically with `@EnableConfigurationProperties(CircuitBreakerProperties.class)`

Comment: I imported FallbackConfiguration and SpelResolverConfiguration on top of CircuitBreakerConfiguration in order to successfully load the spring context. However, the CircuitBreakerAspect.circuitBreakerAroundAdvice was not entertained when calling @CircuitBreaker annotated bean method. What am I doing wrong?

This is my setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810306/how-to-run-the-springboottest-with-only-a-single-bean-and-with-included-resilien